# How do I count objects/substrings in a very specifically formatted file?

Tags: python, string, split, c-strings

I have a file formatted this way -

```
{'apple': 4, 'orange': 3, 'peach': 1}
{}
{'apple': 1, 'banana': 1}
{'peach': 1}
{}
{}
{'pear': 3}
...
```

`[10k more lines like this]`

I want to create a new text file to store the total count of each of these fruits/objects like this -

```
apple:110
banana:200
pineapple:50
...
```

How do I do this?

> My attempt: I've tried using Python (**If this is confusing, please skip it**) -
>
> ```
> f = open("fruits.txt","r")
> lines = f.readlines()
> f.close()
> g = open("number_of_fruits.txt","a")
>
> for line in lines:                           #Iterating through every line,
>     for character in "{}'":                       #Removing extra characters,
>         line = line.replace(character, "")    
>
>     for i in range(0,line.count(":")):            #Using the number of colons as a counter,
>         line = line[ [m.start() for m in re.finditer("[a-z]",line)][i] : [m.start() for m in re.finditer("[0-9]",line)][i] + 1 ] #Slice the line like this - line[ith time I detect any letter : ith time I detect any number + 1]
>         #And then somehow store that number in temp, slicing however needed for every new fruit
>         #Open a new file
>         #First look if any of the fruits in my line already exist
>         #If they do:
>             #Convert that sliced number part of string to integer, add temp to it, and write it back to the file
>         #else:
>             #Make a newline entry with the object name and the sliced number from line.
> ```
>
> The number of functions in Python is very overwhelming to begin with. And at this point I'm just considering using C, which is already a terrible idea.

Comment: You could use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate each line as a dictionary. Then all you've got to do is aggregate the dictionaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid using eval.

I would opt for treating it as JSON if you can ensure the formatting will be as above.

```
import json
from collections import Counter
with open('fruits.txt') as f:
    counts = Counter()
    for line in f.readlines():
        counts.update(json.loads(line.replace("'", '"')))
```

If you want the output as defined above:

```
for fruit, count in counts.items():
    print(f"{fruit}:{count}")
```

---

### Updated Answer

Based on @DarryIG's literal_eval suggestion in comments, negates JSON use.

```
from ast import literal_eval
from collections import Counter
with open('fruits.txt') as f:
    counts = Counter()
    for line in f.readlines():
        counts.update(literal_eval(line))
```

Comment: Sorry, you're right! That's what collections Counter is for! :)

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure how this works, but it doesn't do it, so far

Comment: Based on the data above it works okay. Are you sure the rest of the data conforms to this? If it doesn't work as JSON, this code won't work unfortunately.

Comment: Yep! Works like a charm after the edit! I've never come across json files before. Is there any way I could've known this was a json file (whatever that means)? I tried searching for comma and bracket separated files, but there wasn't any json in there.

Comment: It's not actually valid JSON, which explains my usage of the line.replace() - here I am replacing the single quotes with double quotes to make it valid. But it's close enough to make the tweak and for it to work. I would have a read here if you want to learn more https://www.wikiwand.com/en/JSON

The input file looks more to me like line seperated Python dicts that have been written to a file. The easiest choice would be using something like eval to literally interpret them as so, but it's dangerous, as any valid Python code could be written to your input file and it would be executed.

Comment: @BenjaminRowell--regarding "The easiest choice would be using something like eval"--actually in this case you could use literal_eval as in `counts.update(literal_eval(line))` which is safe and is able to convert the Python string to a dictionary without replace.

Comment: @DarrylG Nice! I've never used that before, will update the post with your suggestion :)

Comment: You can check my updated answer with info on file possibly being ndjson/jsonlines format

Answer (score 1):

using defaultdict and json

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)
with open('fruits.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line.replace("'", '"'))
        for fruit, num in data.items():
            result[fruit] += num
print(result)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'apple': 5, 'orange': 3, 'peach': 2, 'banana': 1, 'pear': 3})
```

EDIT: I would recommend using @BenjaminRowell answer (I upvoted it). I will keep this one just for brevity.

EDIT2 (22 May 2020): If it was using double quotes instead of single quotes this would be [ndjson](https://github.com/ndjson/ndjson-spec)/[jsonlines](http://ndjson.org/) format ([here is interesting discussion](https://github.com/ndjson/ndjson-spec/issues/1) on relationship between the two). You can use [ndjson](https://pypi.org/project/ndjson/) or [jsonlines](https://pypi.org/project/jsonlines/) packages to process it, e.g.:

```
import ndjson
from collections import Counter

with open('sample.txt') as f:
    # if using double quotes, you can do:
    #data = ndjson.load(f)

    # because it uses single quotes - read the whole file and replace the quotes
    data = f.read()
    data = ndjson.loads(data.replace("'", '"'))


    counts = Counter()
    for item in data:
        counts.update(item)
print(counts)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is my first time coming across json files. I'd like to read up on all the answers, I'm just hoping the documentation is comprehensive.

Comment: note that yours is not JSON file. And even the separate lines are not JSON, but can be turned into such by replacing the single quote with double quote.

Comment: I couldn't just comment 'gotcha!, so here's a whole line to say that I understand what you're saying.

Comment: It looks it may be ndjson/jsonlines format - check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in functions of python like [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for evaluate each lines to dictionaries in python:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

with open("input.txt", 'r') as inputFile:
  counts = Counter()
  for line in inputFile:
    a = literal_eval(line)
    counts.update(Counter(a))

print(dict(counts))
```

output:

```
{'apple': 5, 'orange': 3, 'banana': 1, 'peach': 2, 'pear': 3}
```

Comment: if you are going to use `collections.Counter`, just update it like @BenjaminRowell did and eventually convert to dict at the end. no need for constant conversion between dict and Counter. And there is no need of default dict in this case at all, normal dict would do.